# Muliple Lists inside a single ListView

Tags: c#, listview, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

**Pre-info:**
I have a page in an app with a setup like this:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <ListView>
        //Some Grids and simple layout
    </ListView>

    <ListView>
        //Huge nested ListView containing another ListView
        <ListView>
            //Further nesting with grids and layout
        </ListView>
    </ListView>

    <ListView>
        //Some Grids
    </ListView>

</ScrollViewer>
```

I use MVVM and the object's I am using to bind are at it's most simple something like this:

```
public class Activity
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public IList<NotImportantClass> NotImportantClass{ get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}

public class BaseClass
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public IList<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
}

public ObservableCollection<BaseClass> BindingSource
```

I am developing the app for UWP and the performance with nested ListView's are horrible. After debugging with the elements from the server it is above 4000 elements that are placed out.
I did read something about grouped ListView for WPF, but most of the lecture and articles I have seen just approaches it with one List and uses a key based on that.

The Title-property can be used as a key, I just need some smart way to use linq or something to use Grouped ListView. Any suggestions on how I can approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Typically when you put any `ItemsControl` like your `ListView` inside of a `ScrollViewer` - it obliterates the list control's virtualization. It's possible that just by replacing the three `ListViews` in a `ScrollViewer` with a single `ListView` with an `ItemTemplateSelector` bound to a single concatenated list of items of different types handled by the selector will restore virtualization and make everything work smoothly. Overall - nesting scrollable list controls is bad for users and bad for performance. Nesting them in a `ScrollViewer` should require a `YesIKnowWhatImDoingAndIStillWantToDoIt` flag to be set before it is allowed as it is almost never a good idea.